# Error at build apk using large sqlite3 database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using a sqlite database in my android project. First I was using a database of 184 Kb and the apk is built correctly. But I decided to add blob field to store mp3 files and then the database is 1.2 Gb. Now, with the new database, the build fail. If I remove the new database and build with the old database the build is success but when use the new database the build fail. The error that the build return is `Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'`. I tried to increase the `javaHeapSize` to 4 gb but doesn't work. Any solutions?

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:77)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:165)
at com.android.apkzlib.zip.utils.ByteTracker.fromStream(ByteTracker.java:49)
at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.makeStoredEntry(ZFile.java:1654)
at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1763)...
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be storing mp3 files in the DB, they should be put in the `res/raw` or `assets` folders

Comment: Yes, it is my plan A, but the apk would be 2 gb, so it's not a good solution. Any alternative?

Comment: Yes: let the users download the contents after installing your app. Possibly, as expansion files.